# Kotlin coroutines `runBlocking`

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning Kotlin coroutines. I've read that `runBlocking` is the way to bridge synchronous and asynchronous code. But what is the performance gain if the `runBlocking` stops the UI thread? 
For example, I need to query a database in Android:

```
    val result: Int
    get() = runBlocking { queryDatabase().await() }

private fun queryDatabase(): Deferred<Int> {
    return async {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        var queryResult: Int = 0
        val sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE..."
        try {
            cursor = getHelper().readableDatabase.query(sqlQuery)
            cursor?.moveToFirst()
            queryResult = cursor?.getInt(0) ?: 0
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return@async queryResult
    }
}
```

Querying the database would stop the main thread, so it seems that it would take the same amount of time as synchronous code? Please correct me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Actually you use [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) to call suspending functions in "blocking" code that otherwise wouldn't be callable there or in other words: you use it to call `suspend` functions outside of the coroutine context (in your example the block passed to `async` is the `suspend` function). Also (more obvious, as the name itself implies already), the call then is a blocking call. So in your example it is executed as if there wasn't something like `async` in place. It waits (blocks *interruptibly*) until everything within the `runBlocking`-block is finished.

For example assume a function in your library as follows:

```
suspend fun demo() : Any = TODO()
```

This method would not be callable from, e.g. `main`. For such a case you use `runBlocking` then, e.g.:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  // demo() // this alone wouldn't compile... Error:() Kotlin: Suspend function 'demo' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
  // whereas the following works as intended:
  runBlocking {
    demo()
  } // it also waits until demo()-call is finished which wouldn't happen if you use launch
}
```

Regarding performance gain: actually your application may rather be more responsive instead of being more performant (sometimes also more performant, e.g. if you have multiple parallel actions instead of several sequential ones). In your example however you already block when you assign the variable, so I would say that your app doesn't get more responsive yet. You may rather want to call your query asynchronously and then update the UI as soon as the response is available. So you basically just omit `runBlocking` and rather use something like `launch`. You may also be interested in [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md).

Comment: could you please explain what does "call suspend functions outside of the coroutine context." mean? you mean that suspend is outside the `runBlocking` context? I agree, but the `runBlocking` would return only after the suspend function returns, so there is no speed gain in my optionion. The only difference is that the query is executed on a different thread

Comment: added a sample what I mean... if it's not clear, just ask

Comment: note also that for cases where you actually want to run asynchronously you don't use `runBlocking`...

Comment: updated my answer a bit... also regarding the performance gain... note that your current code is actually nearly the same as a synchronous variant without coroutines... just try to omit `runBlocking` and use `launch` and you basically experience the asynchronous call ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this easier to understand than the documentation

Comment: @Roland above you said "interruptibly", so can I interrupt `demo()` in `main()`? What syntax do I use?  I tried saying `val x = runBlocking { demo() }` and then tried calling `x.interrupt()` but `x` does not appear to be a `Thread`.  I thought it would be a thread because the javadoc for runBlocking says "If this blocked thread is interrupted (see Thread.interrupt), then the coroutine job is cancelled and this runBlocking invocation throws InterruptedException." ([source](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Builders.kt#L28))

Answer (score 85):

> `runBlocking` is the way to bridge synchronous and asynchronous code

I keep bumping into this phrase and it's very misleading.

`runBlocking` is *almost never* a tool you use in production. It undoes the asynchronous, non-blocking nature of coroutines. You can use it if you happen to already have some coroutine-based code that you want to use in a context where coroutines provide no value: in blocking calls. One typical use is JUnit testing, where the test method must just sit and wait for the coroutine to complete.

You can also use it while playing around with coroutines, inside your `main` method.

The misuse of `runBlocking` has become so widespread that the Kotlin team actually tried to add a fail-fast check which would immediately crash your code if you call it on the UI thread. By the time they did this, it was already breaking so much code that they had to remove it.

Comment: The misuse of `runBlocking` has become so widespread that the Kotlin team have actually had to revert change with fail-fast :)

Comment: It was too late :)

Comment: This explanation of revert fail-fast is actually misleading, it's not only problem of a misuasage (which defenetely exist), problem was that there are valid use cases, such as application start, resources cleanup etc, you can see discussion of it on coroutines issue tracker, solution with additional param "yes, block, I know what I'm doing, please do not crash" wouldn't be better imo. One more problem was that it failed on release code, but not on debug, which is wrong strategy which cause bugs, not prevent them

Comment: What should be used instead of runBlocking to call coroutines without blocking?

Comment: @Trevor You should `launch` a coroutine.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, 'Calling runBlocking{} on UI thread will crash', does this mean runBlocking{} will not launch a coroutine ?? Instead of launching a corountine, does this runBlocking{} runs on main thread ??

Comment: @user3410835 `runBlocking` returns the result of the coroutine it starts, which means it must wait for it to complete.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy `runBlocking` launches a new coroutine and it blocks an the thread where it was called until the coroutine completes (and `runBlocking` can return the result of the coroutine it started).

Comment: Would it be appropriate to use `runBlocking` if I'm integrating with old-style code that has spun up a worker thread, and I would like to call a `suspend` function within that thread, and I would like the result of the function syncronously (so launch and async are unsuitable)? Can I call `runBlocking` from within the worker thread? As far as I see it, this is just a bit of a waste of a thread, but that's not so bad is it?

Comment: @Chrispher Yes, that sounds like the target use case of runBlocking:  call suspendable functions from outside a coroutine.

Comment: What if you have to override a function when using Retrofit and your getTokenAuthToken method is async.. I have to call runBlocking to get the token and then return a value. This feels awkward to me because the function has a return value and not a callback function or some other mechanism to handle async.

Comment: The current version of Kotlin as of Arctic Fox no longer has the keyword "launch", so what should we use?  Also, what are we supposed to do with DataStore used for shared preferences?  I tried using "runBlocking()" but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: wrapping few firestore "create document" operations in `runBlocking` is bad idea?

Comment: non-blocking nature of coroutines. - Can you explain this?