# Running asynchronous tasks in synchronous way in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to run a 'batch' job of Firebase Firestore. Since batch job is asynchronous, and every batch processes only 500 documents, I have created an array of batch jobs that I want to run in a synchronous way, so that I know exactly when the last batch is done, and then proceed with the next operation.

However, to do this in Kotlin, when I read up, I have come across a sleuth of jargons like runBlocking, Coroutine, Dispatcher, async, await, Context, Suspend, launch, join, Scope, Deferred, Continuation, CommonPool

Furthermore, many of the posts say that in the latest version of Kotlin things have changed. Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) talks about runBlocking, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332499/7333299) says runBlocking is bad thing.

After some trial and error I got this to get compiled

```
suspend fun doTheThing() {

   for ( b in batchArray) {
      coroutineScope {
      val job = async { b.commit() }
      job.await()
  }}
}
```

However, now I am getting the error saying "Suspend function 'doTheThing' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"
I am just confused at the moment. I just want to do those calls in sequence, or wait till all of those are done. Not sure what is the right syntax to get this done, and what concepts am I getting wrong.

---

**Update**: Following code snippet seems to be working:

```
for ( b in batchArray) {
    runBlocking {b.commit()}
}
```

Is it a good practice to do it like this?

Answer (score 2):

Coroutines are usually created by different builders in a context of some coroutine scope. Like the builders, a suspend function runs in a coroutine scope and as such should be called within a coroutine scope which can be provided either by calling within a coroutine, a suspend function or explicitly from a defined scope.

A CoroutineScope is an interface which contains a single property only which is the [coroutineContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/index.html). You can simply create your own scope by implementing the CoroutineScope interface and override your own coroutine context.

```
val myCoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Job() + Dispatchers.Main
}
```

From your scope, you can use builders like launch, async, produce etc.

You can refactor your function to

```
suspend fun doTheThing() = coroutineScope{
for ( b in batchArray) {
    b.commit()
   }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    myCoroutineScope.launch {
        doTheThing()
        println("Completed")   
      }
}
```

I used launch here since we don't really care about the results. The suspend function will suspend the parent coroutinescope until it completes its execution.

You can also choose to run your scope in another dispatcher

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

myCoroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    doTheThing()
    println("Completed")
   }
}
```

For better results where we don't want cancellation of any child coroutine to cancel the scope we use a SuperVisor Job in place of the regular Job.

```
val myCoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your first option. It did compile, but when I ran the code I got the exception saying ```Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'```

Thanks for your explanation on Scope. Also mind explaining what is a Dispatcher and what these different dispatchers are?

Comment: A Dispatchers can be thought of as the thing running the coroutine. They are to Coroutines what the thread pool is to Threads. The different dispatchers in coroutines are IO, default and unconfined.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have run into some other issues with my code, and unable to execute (mentioned in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479331/accessing-hidden-field-error-coming-at-run-time-in-android-kotlin-code)). Will update how it goes after I manage to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to do it like this?

No, `runBlocking` is definitely the wrong thing to do. It will block the main thread of your application and possibly crash it with an ANR. However, the particular way you wrote the code means that you can just as well remove `runBlocking` and get the exact same behavior. `b.commit()` is a plain async call, it immediately returns a `Task` object, which means you haven't achieved your desired goal of waiting for a batch to complete before submitting the next one.

Now, on to a correct solution that leverages coroutines.

Put the `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` dependency on the classpath. This will give you the `suspend fun Task.await()` extension function and allow you to construct a suspending call `b.commit().await()`, which doesn't complete until the batch is committed.

With that in place you can write your function like this:

```
fun CoroutineScope.doTheThing(batchArray: List<Batch>) {
    launch {
        for (b in batchArray) {
            b.commit().await()
        }
        // add logic here for what to do when all batches are done
    }
}
```

In order to call it, you need a `CoroutineScope`. If you don't know yet about structured concurrency and how to use it, take a look at the doc of [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) for a quick start.

Note that the caller of `submitAll` won't block until all the batches are done, it will instead launch a coroutine in the background and continue. The launched coroutine will, however, *suspend* while a batch is in progress, resume when it's done, start the next job, suspend, and so on until all are done. While it's suspended, it won't occupy an thread.

Comment: Thanks. This coupled with the coroutine example given by @dani-chuks does seem to compile. I am unable to execute due to some problem that I have run into mentioned in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479331/accessing-hidden-field-error-coming-at-run-time-in-android-kotlin-code). Will update how it goes after I manage to fix that issue.

Comment: Do note that @dani-chucks showed you the outdated way of introducing the `CoroutineScope` to your application. I urge you to study its documentation, which shows a simpler and less error-prone way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading the documentation now. Although I must say that I am getting muddled in this overflow of jargons at the moment. Thanks for looking into it though. I'll get back with further questions if I have.

Comment: Documentation that you have shared is not an easy read as it doesn't have simple examples, and is full of terminologies. Other documentations either have non preferred "runBlocking" or other such "non recommended" solutions. It is not even easy to figure out what is the the latest recommendation. And it seems same thing can be achieved in multiple ways. So all documentations look bit different. Wish there was an easier way of doing what I wanted here. Not sure why it has to be this complex.

Comment: All it takes is the few lines I have shown. You can call it with `GlobalScope.doTheThing()`, but that's not recommended. The reason recommendations are changing is that this part of Kotlin is under vigorous development. Structured concurrency (that's what those scopes are about) is essential to building a good-quality app without severe leaks, but there are many examples floating around from the experimental days of coroutines, which didn't have it. Also, best-practice idioms of yesterday turn into out-of-the-box components of today, (such as the `by MainScope` delegate I'm recommending).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution below where your main function from which you are starting you batch job operation you need to define on which thread all 500 documents will process. 
So you initialise a Coroutine scope with IO dispatcher.And call you main processing method inside it.

There are three dispatchers in Kotlin

- **IO** for network and disk IO related work.
- **Default** used for complex operations like list traversal or
  mathematical operations.
- **Main** for positing results to UI or UI related operations.

Now, since you want all 500 documents to process in parallel so you create a synchronous block inside that background thread. 
This synchronous block will not be completed unless all the asynchronous blocks (.commit) operation is not completed.

I guess in this way you can achieve the behavior you want. Please see the code for same below:

```
fun initialFunction() {

   //inside this function start the Coroutine using launch
   //using Dispatcher.IO will perform execution of coroutine in background/IO
   CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

      //call your method which will process batch job asynchronously
      doTheThing()

   }
}

suspend fun doTheThing() {
  //now start your blocking call, this execute following block 
  //synchronously 
  runBlocking {
     for ( b in batchArray) {

     //commit will run synchronously and following nested coroutine
     //will wait for job to get completed 
     launch {
        val job = async { b.commit() }
        job.await()
     }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it because a suspend function should never block. It would be better to remove `suspend` and name it something like `doTheThingBlocking` to make it clear that it blocks. But even then, this whole strategy is wrong because it wastes an extra thread to wait for other thread(s) that `commit()` uses.