# How do I wait for the first function to finish before executing the second function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

So i have a simple code

```
try_button.setOnClickListener {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            fun1()
            fun2()
        }
    }

private fun fun1(){
    Timer().schedule(5000){
        println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
    }
}
private fun fun2(){
    println("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
}
```

I try want to run the first function, after the first function is finished, continue to second function.

I try so many code but I always get a result

```
THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION
THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION
```

Can I wait for the first function to finished before continue to the second function?

Comment: use runBlocking.

Comment: @RishabhKumarSingh I would like to point out for anyone that might see this comment that this is [**very dangerous advice**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332499/7366707); `runBlocking` should never be used in production code except in extremely specific circumstances. (also, it wouldn't actually solve the problem here at all, because both functions return immediately without suspending, and the issue at hand here is more of a logic error...)

Comment: @Moira Thank you very much. A doubt, If I want a database operation and can't proceed without its result. How do I manage then? Should I not use suspend functions?

Answer (score 3):

According to your usecase better option will be using `async` and `await` what it does basically, you are gonna request to fun1 it waits for the result1 once it is done it will go for further process which is fun2 even though you have put some delay in fun1 it will still run sequentially fun1 then fun2, here is the code snippet:

*Just Regular function getting data from somewhere*

```
private suspend fun fun1(): String {
    delay(3000L)
    return "Result 1"
}


private fun fun2(): String {
    return "Result 2"
}
```

*Sequential Call:*

```
   val result1 = async {
            fun1()
        }
        println(result1.await())


        val result2 = async {
            fun2()
        }
        println(result2.await())
```

*output*:

```
Result 1
Result 2
```

Comment: There's no need to use async/await for fun2 since fun2 is just a regular but not a suspending function

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin the usecase was, he wanted something that runs sequentially even though with the delays and its not only about suspending function. what ``async`` does it makes the request either it succeeds or faileds and what ``await`` does it waits for the result for further process. same goes with the fun2. async/await are not only for suspending function but rather it helps to make code sequential or you can make it parallel as well.
further i would refer this kotlinconf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0kfnydnFWI

Comment: Suspending functions are sequential by default so there's no need for async/await. Async/await is used if you want to run multiple coroutines concurrently that produce results. Async produces a deferred object similar to Java Feature or JavaScript Promise. The important part is that Async is hot so it starts execution right away. See also https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default.

Comment: Just to make the "hot" part clearer, using your code, fun1 and fun2 would be called right away so if you put a print statement at the top of the two functions, it would print both concurrently even if the result is returned sequentially. It's exactly the opposite of what the OP wanted, concurrent vs sequential execution.

Answer (score 1):

Add suspend keyword. It will suspend your execution

```
try_button.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                fun1()
                fun2()
            }
        }

suspend fun fun1(){
    delay(1000)
    println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
}
fun fun2(){
    println("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works, but it didn't work if my fun1 is try to get result from Firebase

Answer (score 1):

You're using `launch` but not using `suspend` functions. Make your functions suspend functions and use `delay`, which is a `suspend`ing function designed to wait.

```
try_button.setOnClickListener {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            fun1()
            fun2()
        }
    }

private suspend fun fun1(){
    delay(5000)
    println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
}
private suspend fun fun2(){
    println("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
}
```

Please review [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) for more information on how coroutines work.

Comment: There's no need to suspend fun2

Answer (score 1):

Using suspend for fun1 is correct if you replace

```
Timer().schedule(5000) {
    println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
}
```

with

```
delay(5000L)
println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
```

so:

```
private suspend fun fun1() {
    delay(5000L)
    println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
}

private fun fun2() {
    println("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
}
```

Timer().schedule(5000) isn't a suspending function so suspending fun1 doesn't do anything. As a matter of fact Timer().schedule(5000) uses a different thread than GlobalScope.launch and thus the action is executed outside the coroutine thread pool meaning you'd not be able to synchronize the two function calls except manually (e.g. using a semaphore).

Using async / await would be a solution if you want to synchronize on the results (your question implies otherwise). If you want to use async, only fun1 would need an async/await since fun2 is just a regular function (no delay, no suspension needed).

**Just for fun, solution using a Semaphore**

```
val lock = Semaphore(1)

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        fun1()
        fun2()
    }
}

private suspend fun fun1() {
    lock.acquire()
    Timer().schedule(5000) {
        println("THIS IS THE FIRST FUNCTION")
        lock.release()
    }
}

private suspend fun fun2() {
    lock.acquire()
    println("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
}
```

Semaphore can be acquired once before it suspends (fun2) and resumes once the permit is released (by fun1).