# How to read initial values from a preferences dataStore in Kotlin/Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I can create a dataStore, and a file appears, but I don't seem to be able to get any values out of the file.

I'm new to Kotlin and Android.  I wrote a simple (but useful) app, and then tried to persist its state, but I got completely stuck for about 3 days now.  So I've created what I think is a minimal example below (doing something even simpler.)

This app has a button with a number on it (actually two numbers, but that's just to help with debugging.)  Press the button to increment the number.  The count should be restored even if the app is stopped and reinitialised.

The button should increment both copies of the count.  Only the left one increments.  And after restarting the app, both are always reset to 500.

Writing to the dataStore (using updateCount) does result in a MY_PREFS file being created.  As far as I can tell, subsequent updates rewrite the file, but apparently don't change the contents (using the device manager to probe the file on the emulated device.)

It looks as though the file is never being read.  The getInitialCount and getLiveCount only ever return their default values (300 or 500) even though the button clearly increments.

Any help gratefully received, thank you.

```
data class MyState(val count: Int)

private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(
    name = "MY_PREFS"
)

class MyStateRepository(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) {
    private val countKey = intPreferencesKey("COUNT")

    val myStateFlow: Flow<MyState> = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) emit(emptyPreferences()) else throw exception
        }.map { preferences ->
            MyState(preferences[countKey] ?: 100)
        }

    suspend fun updateCount(newCount: Int) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences -> preferences[countKey] = newCount }
    }

    suspend fun getInitialCount(): Int {
        return dataStore.data.first()[countKey] ?: 300
    }

    suspend fun getLiveCount(): Int {
        return dataStore.data
            .map { preferences -> preferences[countKey] ?: 400 }
            .asLiveData().value ?: 500
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var myStateRepository: MyStateRepository
    //Unused: lateinit var myStateFlow: Flow<MyState>

    // I want to initialise this (later) from the dataStore.  Defaulting to 200
    private var currentCount by mutableIntStateOf(200)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        myStateRepository = runBlocking { MyStateRepository(dataStore) }
        //        currentCount = runBlocking { myStateRepository.getInitialCount() }
        currentCount = runBlocking { myStateRepository.getLiveCount() }
        setContent { Counter() }
    }


    @Composable
    private fun Counter() {
        Button(onClick = {
            currentCount = currentCount + 1;
            runBlocking { myStateRepository.updateCount(currentCount) }
        },
            content = { Text(text = "$currentCount ${runBlocking { myStateRepository.getLiveCount() }}") })
    }
}
```

based on some random web pages I've also added these dependencies to build.gradle.kts:

```
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
```

Comment: Why are you creating the repository in your activity? Have you thought about creating a view model?

Comment: Where should I create the repo?  (I think having a view model will only make this more complicated, won't it?)

Comment: Also, why are you using runBlocking for your suspend methods? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331373/kotlin-coroutines-runblocking).

Comment: Good question - because this is initialisation.  I don't want anything to start until we've read the initial parameters.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Do you think I have a race condition in the reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix you could replace unnecesary `.asLiveData().value` with `.firstOrNull()`, it should start functioning.

To get the current count you should use `myStateFlow` that is already initialized with a default value `100`.

```
suspend fun getCount(): Int {
    return myStateFlow.first().count
}
```

Overall, in your composable you will collect `StateFlow` containing preferences from a `ViewModel` and invoke update callbacks.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var myStateRepository: MyStateRepository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        myStateRepository = MyStateRepository(dataStore)
        // Prints the initial value on launch
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val count = myStateRepository.getCount()
            println("One time count = $count")
        }
        setContent {
            Counter(
                // State should come from a ViewModel
                state = myStateRepository.myStateFlow,
                onUpdate = { newCount ->
                    // Should happen in a ViewModel as viewModelScope.launch
                    lifecycleScope.launch { myStateRepository.updateCount(newCount) }
                },
            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Counter(
        state: Flow<MyState>,
        onUpdate: (Int) -> Unit,
    ) {
        val count = state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(MyState(0))
        Button(
            onClick = { onUpdate(count.value.count + 1) }
        ) {
            Text(text = "${count.value.count}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  .firstOrNull() got it working as you promised. I shouldn't blindly guess what functions do...  Next step is to find out how to do the model view stuff properly in kotlin -- thank you for the pointers.